# My Weka Java Code result *WEKA*DUMMY*STRING*FOR*STRING*ATTRIBUTES*

Tags: java, eclipse, weka

I have a J48 model that generated through WEKA GUI and planning to use it on my WEKA JAVA Code. I want to use the model to predict my data on the fly. My code as follow:

```
public static void dt(String type, String bitrate, String resolution, String fps, String duration){
    String rootPath="/home/weka/Documents/";

    Attribute attr1 = new Attribute("type", (FastVector) null);
    Attribute attr2 = new Attribute("bitrate", (FastVector) null);
    Attribute attr3 = new Attribute("resolution", (FastVector) null);
    Attribute attr4 = new Attribute("fps", (FastVector) null);
    Attribute attr5 = new Attribute("duration", (FastVector) null);
    Attribute attr6 = new Attribute("class", (FastVector) null);

    FastVector attributes = new FastVector();

    attributes.addElement(attr1);
    attributes.addElement(attr2);
    attributes.addElement(attr3);
    attributes.addElement(attr4);
    attributes.addElement(attr5);
    attributes.addElement(attr6);

    Instances testing = new Instances("Test-dataset", attributes, 0);
    testing.setClassIndex(testing.numAttributes() - 1);

    double[] values = new double[testing.numAttributes()];

    values[0] = testing.attribute(0).addStringValue(type);
    values[1] = testing.attribute(1).addStringValue(bitrate);
    values[2] = testing.attribute(2).addStringValue(resolution);
    values[3] = testing.attribute(3).addStringValue(fps);
    values[4] = testing.attribute(4).addStringValue(duration);

    Instance inst = new Instance(1.0, values);

    inst.setValue(testing.attribute(0), values[0]);
    inst.setValue(testing.attribute(1), values[1]);
    inst.setValue(testing.attribute(2), values[2]);
    inst.setValue(testing.attribute(3), values[3]);
    inst.setValue(testing.attribute(4), values[4]);

    System.out.println("The instance: "+inst);

    testing.add(inst);

    try {
        Classifier cls = (Classifier) weka.core.SerializationHelper.read(rootPath+"multimedia.model");
        double myValue = cls.classifyInstance(testing.lastInstance());
        String prediction = testing.classAttribute().value((int) myValue);

        System.out.println("The predicted value of the data = "+prediction);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The result of my code :

```
==Service parameter information==
Service ID : 1
Type : audio
Bitrate : 96
Resolution : 0
FPS : 0
Duration : 20
The instance: 1,1,1,1,1,0
The predicted value of the data = *WEKA*DUMMY*STRING*FOR*STRING*ATTRIBUTES*
```

It seems that my value did not included in the instance and resulting Weka Dummy message. Where is my code do wrong? i already search the tutorial and googling the answer, but i can't find one.

Thank you.

Comment: Unrelated: you should create an array/list to hold your **Attribute** objects. Naming stuff a1, a2, .. is always a good indication that you are doing something wrong. You see, you wouldn't need 6 calls to attributes.addElement if those attributes were already in a list for example.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your comment GhostCat. I got help from my friend to solve this problem. The updated code as follow:

```
public static void dt(String type, String bitrate, String resolution, String fps, String duration){
    String rootPath="/home/weka/Documents/";

    Attribute attr1 = new Attribute("type", (FastVector) null);
    //Attribute attr2 = new Attribute("bitrate", (FastVector) null);
    Attribute attr2 = new Attribute("bitrate");
    Attribute attr3 = new Attribute("resolution", (FastVector) null);
    //Attribute attr4 = new Attribute("fps", (FastVector) null);
    Attribute attr4 = new Attribute("fps");
    //Attribute attr5 = new Attribute("duration", (FastVector) null);
    Attribute attr5 = new Attribute("duration");
    Attribute attr6 = new Attribute("class", (FastVector) null);

    FastVector attributes = new FastVector();

    attributes.addElement(attr1);
    attributes.addElement(attr2);
    attributes.addElement(attr3);
    attributes.addElement(attr4);
    attributes.addElement(attr5);
    attributes.addElement(attr6);


    Instances testing = new Instances("multimedia", attributes, 0);
    testing.setClassIndex(testing.numAttributes() - 1);

    double[] values = new double[testing.numAttributes()];
    values[0] = testing.attribute(0).addStringValue(type);
    values[1] = Integer.parseInt(bitrate);
    values[2] = testing.attribute(2).addStringValue(resolution);
    values[3] = Integer.parseInt(fps);
    values[4] = Integer.parseInt(duration);

    Instance test = new Instance(1, values);
    testing.add(test);

    System.out.println("The instance: "+testing);

    try {
        Classifier cls = (Classifier) weka.core.SerializationHelper.read(rootPath+"multimedia.model");
        //double myValue = cls.classifyInstance(testing.lastInstance());
        //double myValue = cls.classifyInstance(testing.firstInstance());
        //String prediction = testing.classAttribute().value((int) myValue);
        System.out.println(cls.classifyInstance(testing.firstInstance()));
        //String prediction = testing.classAttribute().value((int) myValue);

        //System.out.println("The predicted value of the data = "+prediction);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The result as follow:

```
    Received JSON : {"id":"1","duration":"30","flag":"start","fps":"24","bitrate":"128","resolution":"720p","type":"video"}

==Service parameter information==
Service ID : 1
Type : video
Bitrate : 128
Resolution : 720p
FPS : 24
Duration : 30
The instance: @relation multimedia

@attribute type string
@attribute bitrate numeric
@attribute resolution string
@attribute fps numeric
@attribute duration numeric
@attribute class string

@data
video,128,720p,24,30,*WEKA*DUMMY*STRING*FOR*STRING*ATTRIBUTES*
0.0
```

It seems that we already create the instance based on new data. However, it cannot classified by the model and resulting *WEKA*DUMMY*STRING*FOR*STRING*ATTRIBUTES*. Can you or anyone help me, why the result like this?Thank you...